# Can you put multiple executable scripts in one directory, and by sourcing that directory make all of those commands available?

Tags: bash, shell, executable, source

I want to put a bunch of executable scripts in the .command dir (which is also executable), and then only have to source that directory in my .bash_profile. Is this possible? I can get this to work with one file. But when adding a second file, the second file's commands aren't available in the shell.

my .bashprofile

```
source ~/.commands/*
```

my .commands folder

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 christopherreece  staff   108 Dec 14 08:55 server_utils.sh
-rwxr-xr-x   1 christopherreece  staff    23 Dec 14 09:04 short
```

contents of short

```
echo 'a short program'
```

contests of server_utils.sh

```
function upfile {
  scp $1 root@myserveripadress:~/
}
```

Shell input and output.

```
$ hello
hello

$ short
-bash: short: command not found
```

Comment: Where did `hello` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with one `source`. The first argument is taken as the file name, the others show up as the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`... in the sourced script.

```
$ cat test.src 
echo hello $1
$ source test.src there
hello there
```

But you could do it with a loop:

```
for f in ~/commands/*.src; do
    source "$f"
done
```

<sub>(As an aside, having stuff like that include only files with a certain extension is quite useful if you use an editor that leaves backup files with a trailing `~`. The backup copies don't become accidentally active, then.)</sub>

Though note that if you have a sourced script that contains plain commands (like that `echo` above or your `short`), they'll be executed when the script is `source`d. They don't generate any functions in the sourcing shell.

```
$ cat test2.src 
echo "shows when sourced"
func() {
    echo "shows when function used"
} 
$ source test2.src 
shows when sourced
$ func
shows when function used
```

---

If you want to have executable scripts instead, the kind where the script runs when you give its name as a command, put them somewhere in `PATH` (I'd suggest using `~/bin` for that), give them the execute permission and put proper hashbangs in the beginning of the scripts (`#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` or whatever)